# How to open setting page(Permission) using react native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

For opening the Setting page from our app we can use the as per React Native. Here I used the React native (latest version)

```
Linking.openSettings()
```

above code is working some of the Android devices and some of the android devices its notworking.
Tested with Samsung and Redmi devices above code not working properly. some of the realer device its working fine. even some of the android emulator its working fine.